# How to serialize JSON object

Tags: php, json, serialization

I created one demo page to convert Associative Array to JSON string by using following code.

```
$test = array("name"=>"test","city"=>"xyz","zipcode"=>"98989");
echo json_encode($test);
```

**I am Getting following Output**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "city": "xyz",
    "zipcode": "98989"
}
```

**My Expected Output**

```
"{
    \"name\": \"test\",
    \"city\": \"xyz\",
    \"zipcode\": \"98989\"
}"
```

Because I am getting error **"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})** in shipstation API. How can achieve my expected output.

**Actual Code**

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    $post_fields = array(
                  "orderNumber" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                  "orderDate" => "2015-06-29T08:46:27.0000000",
                  "shipByDate" => "2015-07-05T00:00:00.0000000",
                  "orderStatus" => "awaiting_shipment",
                  "billTo" => array("name"=>"ABCD PVT LTD"),
                  "shipTo" => array("name"=>"XYZ PVT LTD Bombay","company"=>"PTR","street1"=>"301,Park Street","city"=>"Sydney","postalCode"=>"20500","country"=>"Australia","residential"=>true),
                  "items" => array(
                                    array(
                                      "name"=>"PTR Last order by ABC #9999",
                                      "quantity"=>2,
                                      "unitPrice"=>99.99,
                                      "options"=>array("name"=>"SIZE","value"=>"Large"),
                                      "amountPaid"=> 199.98,
                                      "paymentMethod"=>"Credit Card",
                                      "shipDate"=>"2015-07-02"
                                      )
                                    )
                            );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($post_fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       "Content-Type: application/json",
       "Authorization: < Enter your Basic Authorization string here >"
   ));
```

Comment: Down voter please comment to improve my question.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the API requires that output. You should show the code that throws the error.

Comment: @Juhana I already given my expected output which API requires.

Comment: try this `echo json_encode(json_encode($test), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: The error you have specified is saying that it can't parse with the \".... it looks like you're already trying to send it a string which had been escaped (addslashes). Try and json_decode right after your e code line and you will see that works fine. For more accurate help provide an actual example that breaks.

Comment: If you think the API really requires broken JSON, then sure, go ahead with that plan. Let us know how it works for you. (If you think the backslashes are required because they're in the error message, that's not what the error message means.)

Comment: @BenCummins I added my actual code pls check and help me

Comment: @Juhana I added my actual code pls check and help me

Answer (score 2):

use addslashes() php function

```
$test = array("name" => "test", "city" => "xyz", "zipcode" => "98989");
$data = json_encode($test);
echo $data = addslashes($data);
```

Comment: But It returns expected output.

Comment: Sorry bu't that, I haven't drank my coffee yep

Comment: @ka_lin: plz use 2 cups. :p

Comment: @ka_lin : No problem dear. Its ok.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using the json_encode()  to convert the array to a string, however, I am pretty sure you just need to drop json_encode() and pass the array directly into the POSTFIELDS parameter.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_fields);
```

Also, in your original message, you have "respected output" and "expected output" - I think thats also confusing.

I believe you meant, the respected output is **required**, and instead of expected output, thats the **actual** output.

Comment: Expected output that I want

Comment: try what I've suggested. I would be very suprised that any API would expect a stringified JSON object as its payload.

Comment: Check documentation link http://www.shipstation.com/developer-api/#/reference/orders/createupdate-order/create/update-order

Comment: I also checking you provided code but getting error

Comment: Okay, so I've checked the API, and it does actually like the way you were doing it originally was right. The API on their website is misleading as its showing you the JSON inside a string. Are you echoing back the response the API gives you?

Comment: It gives me valid JSON response.

Comment: Response back from the shipstation API ? whats the issue then?

Comment: It gives me valid json format as response but when I want to post as request then it want me request like my expected output.